# Act_as_taggable: any way to clean tag used one time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Act_as_taggable Gem in my project, but I have a lot of confusion in my tag: I have about 10000 tags where 6000 of them are used just one time.

I have autocomplete and autocomplete on 10000 tags very slow.

Any way to clean tags used only one time?

Answer (score 0):

What version of act_as_taggable are you on ? I am on the latest version and I have two tables:

```
taggings -> id, tag_id, taggable_id, taggable_type, tagger_id, tagger_type, context, created_at
tags -> id, name, taggings_count
```

From tags.taggings_count you get the number of how often the tag is used. You can get rid of the tags that are used only once, but make sure that you also get rid of entries in taggings that refer to it in order to keep it consistent (tags.id == taggable.tag_id).
Also make sure that you have an index on tags.name (which should be by default, but double check).

UPDATE:

To remove tags? You want to do this inside your application ? I.e. listing all the tags on the page and have a remove button? Or are you going to delete it manually in the sql console via a hand-made statement ? I would recommend the first option as this is more clean and simple: Take a look at the [Usage Section of act_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) - it shows how to remove tags.

Comment: I have version 3.0.1, I don't have the taggings_count column.

Comment: Go on 3.0.2 and you will have it :)

Comment: I upgraded to 4.0 and everything is fine. By the way I can now select all Tag with count = 1 but I don't know how I can remove also the associated taggings.

Comment: I updated the answer - you can remove tags via i.e.: @user.tag_list.remove("awesome") # remove a single tag ... take a look at the link I added to the gem which explains it. Of course you can create your own sql statement that does it for you - however, this is a safe way of doing it to keep things consistent & you can use it whenever required from within the application you build.

Comment: I know the gem. I just need a one time clean task to remove al the tags used just 1 time. I'm migrating a cms and I come from a CMS without autocomplete, a lot of tags are not useful. 

I can make an array of tags with count = 1, but when I have these tags how can I remove the elements from the "Taggings" join table?

Comment: are you using mysql? If so what you need to do is make sure you have on delete cascade in place - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28SQL.90%29.aspx      It specifies that if an attempt is made to delete a row with a key referenced by foreign keys in existing rows in other tables, all rows that contain those foreign keys are also deleted. However, I took a quick look and it doesn't appear as if these constraints are in place.

Comment: So what you can do is have a statement that outputs all ID's of tags you are going to delete. Then delete all taggings where tag_id equals to one of the id's you collected previously. Once that's done delete the tags. So essentially you have three statements - perhaps you want to test your statements before applying to live. You can also pack this in a script whereby you commit at the end so to make sure its getting rolled back if things go wrong.